What's the difference He said that they would stay here for three days vs. they will stay here ~

He said that they would stay here for three days. vs.


He said that they will stay here for three days.

What's the difference between the sentences? The only difference is would vs. will

The first version, with backshift, is correct generally.
The second version, without backshift, is possible only if the occasion is still future, for example, the guests have not arrived.

To Seow I think that you are a specialist when it comes to English.
